# ios using filteredArrayUsingPredicate NSPredicate with NSString not working

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nspredicate

I'm using to get some of the content of nsmutable array and it work fine if I don't use nsstring to make the query:

```
NSLog(@"user information %@", [usersInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == 'Joe", @"id"]]);
```

But try to use a nsstring to query for the user it doesn't work:

```
NSString *user="Joe";

NSLog(@"user information %@", [usersInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == user", @"id"]]]);
```

any of you knows what I'm doing wrong? or what would be the best of doing it using NSString to query for users?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use:

```
NSLog(@"user information %@", [usersInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%K == '%@'",@"id",user]]]);
```

When you use:

```
NSLog(@"user information %@", [usersInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == user", @"id"]]]);"
```

The user will be a part of the string, it won't replace with the content of the NSString object.

Comment: in this line NSLog(@"user information %@", [usersInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%K == '%@'",user], @"id"]]]); I get this error "more % conversions that data arguments". How can I fix?

Comment: @HelenaM: I fixed the issue, check now

Comment: I strongly recommend against using `stringWithFormat` when building predicates. This will fail as soon as `user` contains any special characters such as quotes.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Your edit to this answer seems incorrect to me. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"id",user]` now expands to `@"id == Joe"`, so that you have `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == Joe"]` **without** the necessary quotes around the string.

Comment: @MartinR OH.  I just noticed he's using `+stringWithFormat`.  Yep, you're absolutely correct.

Comment: -1 for the reason @MartinR specified above.  The `+stringWithFormat:` call is unnecessary and incorrect.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Then how can be the user pass a string value stored in an NSObject ? Can you explain how can I do that without using `stringWithFormat` ?

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Your edit was incorrect, you forgot to put single quotes around the string, martin is mentioned that

Comment: @MidhunMP yes, but your answer is still incorrect.  The extra call to `+stringWithFormat:` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
NSString *user = @"Joe";
... [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == user", @"id"]
```

you seem to expect that "user" in the predicate is replaced by the contents ("Joe") of the NSString variable, but this is not correct.

You have to give the string
as another argument to the predicate and add the `%@` format that will be expanded by the string.

```
NSString *user = @"Joe";
... [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"id", user]
```

Here `%K` (which is var arg substitution for a *key path*) will be
substituted by the key `"id"`, and `%@` (which is
var arg substitution for an object value) will be substituted
by the contents of the `user` variable.

Using `%K` expansion instead of

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", user]
```

has the advantage that it works correctly even if the key is a
reserved word in the predicate format string syntax.

Comment: Wow! A downvote without explaining comment on a 4-year old answer. That is really helpful for future readers!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to gues why you are using `"%K == 'Joe"`

Anyways, You can use predicate as:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"object.property LIKE[c] %@", stringValue];
```

Or,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"object.property==[c] %@", stringValue];
```

Comment: Hi anoop :) Nice to see you again. Please check the question again. The first code is working for the OP, what the issue is OP try to store the value JOE in a `NSString` object and try to use it. It is not working. (because op added the object name inside the "" )

Comment: the reason I'm using %k is because is a xml content. and looks like this <user id="Joe"

Comment: @MidhunMP: very busy with proj yaar. 15-16hours daily. Actually I was pointing to 'Joe" kind of syntactical err. Any ways you solved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this：

```
NSString *user="Joe";

NSLog(@"user information %@", [usersInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", user]]]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your predicate format string before don't try to add property name inside predicate format :

```
NSString *predicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ == %%@",@"id"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateFormat, @"Joe"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [mutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: There is no reason to use stringWithFormat to create the format string. And if the key happens to be a reserved word for the predicate syntax then this will crash at runtime.